# Swing/awt gcd calculator

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have to create a calculator in java swing/awt that computes different functions.

For example it needs to compute the GCD.
First I have created the UI, and then the actionPerformed function, but when I execute the `gcd` function in the GUI the screen freezes.

```
calculate2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Get values from text fields
            try {
                int a = Integer.parseInt(input1.getText());
                int b = Integer.parseInt(input2.getText());
                while (a != b) {
                    if(a > b)
                        a = a - b;
                    else
                        a = b - a;
                }

                String result1 = "" + (b);
                result.setText((result1));
            } catch (Exception f) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "ERROR: " + (f.getMessage()));
            }

            String aField = input1.getText();
            String bField = input2.getText();

            if (e.getSource() == calculate2) {

                if ("".equals(aField) || "".equals(bField)) {
                    String emptyFieldWarning;
                    emptyFieldWarning = "One or more fields is/are empty!";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, emptyFieldWarning);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: The GUI freezes because you're stuck at some point in your function. And as @JanDeKock suggested I think you have a mistake in your while loop (see his answer).

Answer (score 3):

In the while loop, in the else branch, the statement should be `b = b - a`